# multisubnet listener

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, listener

Good morning all ,

I have an alwayson instance with a multisubnet listener

I configured RegisterAllProvidersIP = 0 in order to register a single DNS entry

HostRecordTTL is configured at 1200 seconds

I would like if with this configuration I will have timoeout during the failover

if so how much time is needed for the application to connect to the lsitener

thanks

Comment: You want the failover to timeout and fail after 20 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

> if so how much time is needed for the application to connect to the lsitener

Since you said `HostRecordTTL` is set to 1200 seconds, the application will take up to 20 minutes to reconnect after a failover that crosses subnets.

Ideally you should set `RegisterAllProvidersIP = 1`, and update your application's connection string to include `MultiSubnetFailover = True`.  This will provide the best failover experience.

If your application uses a driver that doesn't support this setting, or you can't change the connection string for some other reason, **and** you need to reduce the failover timeout, then you'll need to lower the `HostRecordTTL` setting.

Answer (score -1):

I recently published a new blog showing how you can reduce failover times for [SQL Server on Amazon EC2 instance using Network Load Balancer.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/modernizing-with-aws/reduce-failover-time-sql-server-using-nlb/)

When a legacy application that doesn't support MultiSubnetFailover = True you have to set RegisterAllProvidersIP = 0 but  the failover from a primary to a secondary node can take a long time depending on the TTL (as much as 15 minutes) because it requires a DNS replication. With this solution, you can reduce failover times to around a minute.

Comment: There's no indication the OP's on AWS.  Does this apply on-prem too? You can edit the answer to add detail.